# How can I force Storybook to re-render a component?

Tags: storybook

I am using Storybook with the server project type and while it all works fine watching for changes in the stories directory, the server project I'm watching has template files in a different location.

I have looked for a `watchFiles` option or similar on the `framework.options` config for `@storybook/server-webpack5` but that doesn't seem to be an available option.

I have also tried adding a Node watcher on the template files that triggers a touch on the relevant story file, however while that triggers an update in Webpack, nothing changes in the preview presumably because the story file itself has not changed.

Without some way to watch in this way, it's a pain to work with as there is no hot reloading while you're making changes to template files.

Is anybody aware of some kind of config option or a Storybook API call that could be made to trigger a refresh of story preview?

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but I found this article while looking for something similar: https://dev.to/tmikeschu/leveraging-the-key-prop-to-re-render-storybook-stories-5g3a